# Socket.io return null as data but server is receiving the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

I am new at nodes, express, mongodb and socket.io. Things have been working pretty smooth up and till now. So i am building this small test application where the user inputs his name and then post a question.

The socket.io receives the data (username and question) but upon returning the data is says null. (In the beginning it was working but then i started with installing mongoose and things went wrong from that point on). I work with the express framework and all the necessary modules are installed.

in my **views** this is the code for connection to socket and updating the data:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var socket = io();

        $("#btnAskQuestion").on("click", function(e)
        {
            //get the value of the inputfield and textarea
            var username = $('#inputQuestion').val();
            var question = $('#question').val();
            var result = "<p>Username: </p>" + username + " <br /><br /> " + 
            "<p>Question: </p>" + question + " <br /> <br /> ";
            console.log("Values of inputfield & textarea: " + result);

            //makes the connection to the server and send the data 
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
            socket.emit('sendQuestion', result);
            console.log("Gets send: " +result);
            //alert('test');
        });

        //returns the updated data + visualize it on the page
        socket.on('updateQuestion', function (data) 
        {
            console.log("Updated data: " + data);//data is the username and question = result
            $('#answer').css("border", "4px solid #9C27B0");
            $('#answer').css("borderRadius", "8px");
            $('#answer').css("padding", "10px");
            $('#answer').css("fontSize", "16px");
            $('#answer').append('<li>'+data+'</li>');
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

in my bin>www file i have the following code for the server-side connection:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) 
{
   socket.on('sendQuestion', function (data) 
  {
     console.log("The server received a question");
     console.log(data);

    // send question to ALL clients
    io.sockets.emit("updateQuestion", data.result);
  });
});
```

In chrome browser i run the developer tools and the output is the following screenshot:
http://www.nappdev.be/clientside.png

This is a screenshot from the server-side where it logs the data 
http://www.nappdev.be/serverside.png

I hope somebody can help me out because i don't see why its returning null

Thanks in advance !!1

Comment: What is returning null?  There are no return statements in your code so I don't follow what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edited: just noticed that you are actually sending `data.result` which is null in the first place]

Instead of sending `data.result` send `data`.

Note that this will give you the whole string (username + question). If you only want the question, you will have to parse the received string on the server side and emit only the question to the connected clients.